# How can I hide the extra list items that don't fit within a fixed-height box?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I have boxes that contain `<ul>` list content. These boxes have a slightly variable width but have a **fixed height**. This list content is dynamically generated containing anywhere from 0 - 200 list elements. However, because of the box height, I usually can display only 3-5 at a time. **This is OK**.

However, I have been artificially restricting those lists by using ASP.NET MVC code to only display the first 4 elements. This works in about 90% of cases - some boxes will still have overflow if all of the list items have a lot of text (see below).

[image: Example of overflow problem]

I was wondering if there was a way in CSS to use like the `overflow` property or something and hide the list elements that don't fit? I have tried `overflow: hidden` on the `<ul>` to no avail. I imagine this is because the list doesn't know the height of the box that is is in or something

**Clarification:** Ideally, you wouldn't see any part of the `<li>` that doesn't fit. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/5/)

I don't know how long any of these items will be ahead of time or how many elements their might even be, and the width/height of the box are not modifiable. ***Any ideas?***

**Original Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/1/

**Example of Box HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>these LI's are dynamically generated</li>
        <li>I have no idea of their length ahead of time</li>
        <li>Seth Rollins</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Box CSS:**

```
.box {
    height: 110px;
    width: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
    position: relative;

    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/3/? something like this? Set height for 4 one-line list items, of course...

Comment: No, I don't want it scrollable. I want the `<li>` to be like it doesn't exist (like `display: none`) if it doesn't fit in the box.

Comment: overflow:hidden; http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/4/ ?

Comment: @nevermind you can still see the top-piece of list item in the box. That doesn't look clean. It needs to be completely hidden (akin to making that specific item `<li style="display: none">` http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/5/

Comment: Yes, now i understand, you will need javascript/jquery for this... but you could do it in back-end, too (check string length, show just 'shorter' li's, or something...)

Comment: @nevermind Ok, I updated the title of the question. I have to display them in order (regardless of their length). If you can answer with  a good jquery solution that would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have found a way to do this using a pure CSS solution. It involves using flexbox and a bit of cheating to show the bullet using a :before pseudo element.
It even allows centering visible li elements vertically inside the container.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq34sb17/2/

CSS

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    content: '\2022';
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
}
```

and here's the solution applied to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/7/

Comment: I love `display: flex` but unfortunately it doesn't work with older browsers. Our application still has 10,000 users on IE7 (god knows why) so I can't use this. Wish I could though because it is the easiest solution.

Comment: I see. These days it's 99% safe to assume flexbox is a valid option, so please try to state this limitation in your next questions. Good luck!

Comment: I actually ended up using your solution. The jQuery solution I couldn't get to work in my situation. I was worried that if their browser didn't support `flex` then things would get crazy but as it it turns out if it is not supported the `overflow: hidden` CSS just clips and hides what woudln't fit. Not the most elegant-looking on older browsers but it works. Thanks.

Comment: This is cleaver but unfortunately doesn't play well with a11y if you start tabbing through elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution :
http://jsfiddle.net/gc5un34j/3/

Using `element.offsetHeight` to get the height of each element of your list and then comparing it to the container;

JQuery:

```
var listItems = $('ul li'); //The list rows
var listContainer = $('ul'); //The list
var listHeight = 0; //Contains the height of the 4 elements together

for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listHeight += listItems[i].offsetHeight;
    //If the row is bigger than the container, hides it, [0] to access the DOM Element
    if(listContainer[0].offsetHeight < listHeight) { 
        $(listItems[i]).hide();
    }
}
```

Pure JS in browsers supporting QuerySelectors:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li'); //The list rows
var listContainer = document.querySelector('ul'); //The list 

var listHeight = 0; //Contains the height of the 4 elements together

for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listHeight += listItems[i].offsetHeight;

    //If the row is bigger than the container, hides it
    if(listContainer.offsetHeight < listHeight) { 
        listItems[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Tested in Chrome 44 and Firefox

Comment: Nice - this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately in my app the `offsetHeight` is always "0" for some reason (I suspect it has to do with some parent blocks using `position: relative` CSS) so I can't get it to work. Oh well.

Comment: I dont think the `position: relative` is the problem. Maybe you're just reading the property before the DOM has updated, so, before the list has a height.

Comment: Hmm... I have it now in `Document.Ready()` and it still won't read ANY offsets correctly (all values are 0). Really sucks because it is otherwise a perfect solution for me

Answer (score -1):

This will not remove (always!) last child, but, maybe it could be solution (even nicer, imho):

http://jsfiddle.net/emowbngx/6/

```
$('.box').each(function(i) {

  if ($(this).children().height() > $(this).height())

  {
    //$(this).find('li:last-child').css('display','none');
    $(this).find('li').each(function(j) {

      if ($(this).position().top + $(this).height() > $('.box').height()) {

        $(this).css('display', 'none');

      }

    });

  }

});
```

Note: didn't test it too long, try to change text in li's, and see by your self...